# SOAP Response encoding issue

Tags: java, soap, character-encoding, soapui

I have a soap client which call a SOAP WS method. Issue is, when I receive data in JAVA using below code, java parses SOAPMessage using some default encoding. As a result when I print WS response I see some garbage characters.

```
SOAPConnectionFactory connectionFactory = SOAPConnectionFactory.newInstance();
SOAPConnection connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
SOAPMessage response = connection.call(soapMessage, endpoint);
```

So, is there any way, by which I can specify or force .call() method above to use a particular character encoding.

I have tested WS using SOAP UI and RAW XML tab of SOAP UI shows valid characters.

Edit: Am printing and validating presence of garbage characters using below code:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
response.writeTo(baos);
String s2 = new String(baos.toByteArray(), "ISO-8859-1"); // decoding 
System.out.println(s2);
```

Comment: is it possible that you are handling the response incorrectly, or that your terminal cannot display the characters?  how are you printing thre response?

Comment: @jtahlborn Please see my edit.

Comment: my guess is that you are corrupting the response when you are trying to display it.  do you know for a fact that the response is encoded using "iso-8859-1"?

Comment: That is what WS provider say, but how come Raw xml tab in SOAP UI, show correct character if am seeing garbage character in java.

Comment: i don't understand your last comment.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
soapMessage.setProperty(SOAPMessage.WRITE_XML_DECLARATION, Boolean.TRUE);
```

before sending your `soapMessage` variable as a parameter to `call()`.

Refer to this documentation:
http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/soap/SOAPMessage.html#setProperty%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%29

Comment: After adding above I am getting Runtime exception:
javax.xml.soap.write-xml-declaration must have value false or true